# WP8 Folder Access

Tags: windows-phone-8

Can an app access and create a specific folder in the Windows phone 8 environment? I'm looking at building an audiobook player app and want to allow the user to drop these into an audiobook folder on the phones drive itself instead of mixing with the music folder. Could an app at least read from a specific folder outside its isolated storage?

Secondly, if so, is there any equivalent of the ".nomedia" file in Android that my app could insert into the folder to exclude the audiobook folder from being scanned by the music players on the phone?

I'm struggling to find the appropriate documentation that will answer my questions, as most documentation seems specific to WP7

Comment: You are on the right path and off the right mind. Obviously WP 8 can't deal properly with Audiobooks and obviously it should be in a separate folder. I'm offering you bounty, but that's just because I can't throw money at you.

Comment: @Winfred, thank you for the response. I found your bounty description pretty funny as well. :-)

Answer (score 1):

**RE: .nomedia file**

Overall what you're asking for isn't supported and isn't complimentary to the zen of WP8. While I understand your need to create a unique music experience the WP8  media ecosystem is centered around the Music+Video hub and apps should work with it. Creating an experience like you were describing would just feel disjointed and jarring on WP8.

**RE: letting users drag & drop files in file explorer**

Some WP8 phones support having a Micro-SD card added to the phone. That uSD card can be accessed from File Explorer and [WP8 apps can read files from it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720573%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). The uSD card can have a folder called "Music" which would be used by the Music+Video app and invisible to 3rd party apps. However, your app can read any files that aren't in those uSD reserved folders. You can signup to file extensions but most media [WP8 file extensions are reserved for 1st party experiences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207065%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Reservedfiletypes).

**RE: Music Hub Integration**

Please make sure to integrate [your music player into the Music+Video hub](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) otherwise it'll likely get downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but as an avid audiobook user I'd wager that nearly every serious audiobook listener would disagree with your statement on integration of the music player into the music + video section. By the nature of audiobooks, having 10-100 small files in an album would dilute the music players experince. WP8 doesn't properly handle audiobook files, thus the need for a good solution for user downloaded audiobooks (not Audible.com DRM provided books)

Comment: what if the user directly creates a new folder on the phone if it doesn't have a micro-sd (lumia 920 has 32 gb hard drive instead). Can the developer access this folder?